# Moving average, MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the moving average of M = 7 and M = 51. I already have a data that has been imported from the file called data.TP for X, which is the array of amplitudes. Here is my code:

```
M = 51;
N = (1:1:1486);
a = 1;
x = data.Hs;
y = data.Hs;%creating array, it will me modified later
 for n = 1:1:1486;%Going threw the enitre data
   if n > (M-1)/2;%To guarantee that array index would not exceed
      y(n) = (1/M)*sum(x(n:-1:n-((M-1)/2))); %getting average
   else
    y(n) = (10/M)*n;
  end
end
 plot(data.date,data.Tp)
 hold on
 datetick('x','mm/dd')
 plot(data.date, y, '-r')
```

I guess there is an easier way. The formula, which I am trying to implement is : 
Y[n] = 1/M ∑_(k=-((M-1)/2))^(M-1)/2▒(x[n-k]), so its 1/M times the summation from k=-(M-1)/2 to (M-1)/2 of x[n-k]

Comment: The equivalent formula in MATLAB would be `Y(n) = 1/M*sum(x(n:-1:n-M-1))`. Notice you should place a `:-1:` in between the colons because it's a descending "linspace".  The `n-k` is actually performing the summation in reverse (starting with the highest index `x(n-0)` and ending with the lowest index `x(n-M-1)`.

Comment: @MasterHD So I should start from n = 1486 and come down to n=1?

Comment: Can you please write the formula with for loop, I can't understand precisely

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
data = rand(1000,1);
window = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
window=window/norm(window);
smoother=conv(data,window);
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
bar(data);
subplot(2,1,2);
bar(smoother);
```

If you want something more specific post a complete piece of code that reproduces the error.

Comment: It would be better to use the formula, as I am not that advanced in matlab